# Compile error: Sub or Function not defined

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am getting an error and I don't know how to fix it.

What Sub or Function do I have to define here?

This code is highlighted yellow:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() <<<--- Yellow marked line
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
vidWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
vidHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)
    If vidWidth > 1400 Then ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    If vidWidth < 1400 Then ActiveWindow.Zoom = 96
    If vidWidth < 1361 Then ActiveWindow.Zoom = 94
    If vidWidth < 1281 Then ActiveWindow.Zoom = 88
    If vidWidth < 1025 Then ActiveWindow.Zoom = 72
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Error Image:

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you have not declared the function `GetSystemMetrics`.
Ensure you have this line at the top of the routine:

```
Public Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal index As Long) As Long
```

If you have already declared this function, please include the relevant entire
code in your post.

Comment: Maybe make the declaration  PtrSafe to avoid bitness conflicts, as VBA6-Office Versions should be rare after Office 2007 (last VBA6-Version) is EOL more than a year, so we don't need conditional formatting, but gain x86/x64 compatible code.

Comment: That would make it: "Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long".

Comment: Looks good as there are no pointers/handles`, nIndex`and return value should stay `Long`,but I have no x64 Office to test.